# How to partition the Internal SD Card using CWM Recovery?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, partitions, link2sd

How to partition the Internal SD Card using CWM Recovery to use with link2sd. I am using Sony Xperia SL.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend using CWM Recovery for this, but if you're going to this video demonstrates the process -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puLfjeKq_PY

See also -- http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/ClockWorkMod_Instructions#Additional_Commands

My recommendation is to use Minitool Partition Manager on a Windows machine as it's quite clear what's going on & it allows much more control

Comment: How do you partition the internal SD card on windows?

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't notice "internal". That's a whole different game & requires tools specific to your phone/tablet, not all of which are available.

Comment: try -- http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-s/s-development/tutorial-increase-data-partition-t2821058 -- but read **all** the comments as they often have notes or clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you need to create at-least partition on **external** SD card for apps like link2sd to work. I'm not sure about partitioning **internal** SD Card.